# How to design a threading package for an OO language?

Tags: multithreading, oop, programming-languages

It seems difficult  to design a threading package in OO class than in
functional programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a specific question? You have asked an extremely similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771298/how-to-create-a-thread-in-a-class), and I would call this one a duplicate. You can look at the design and answers in that thread to give you an idea.

But we cannot help you until you ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Threading is a difficult concept. But OO languages are perfectly suitable for implementing those.

Define a thread class, that runs in its own thread. Create a subclass and override the required methods.

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, there are zillions of threading libraries for OO languages. Which specific language do you think has difficulties in this area?